# Making a repeating Animation Loop in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json, css-animations

I wanted to make sort an animation loop as an object in JavaScript. The function of the object would go something like this

`var a;
var move = new Repeat(10,function(){a++});`

and it would run at an animation speed, not instantly.

This is my original code (which doesn't work).

```
        function obj(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
        function Repeat(fn,rpt){
            this.function = fn;
            this.repeat = rpt;
            this.counter = 0;
            this.id=setInterval(this.start,5);
            this.start = function(){
                if (this.counter == this.repeat) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    this.repeat++;
                    this.function();
                }
            }
        }


        var box = obj('animation');
        var a=0;
        var move = new Repeat(function(){
            a++;
            box.style.top=a+'px';
            box.style.left=a+'px';
        },300);
        move.start();
```

So I'm looking for suggestions to make this happen.

Comment: Repeat object is defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use Web Animations API to do it, I guess it would be easier https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API